# Proof of $a - b = - (b - a)$, Discrete Math

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-explanation

> Prove that a - b = - (b - a) with the following axioms:
>
> “Associativity of +”: (a + b) + c = a + (b + c)
>
> “Associativity of ·”: (a · b) · c = a · (b · c)
>
> “Symmetry of +”: a + b = b + a
>
> “Symmetry of ·”: a · b = b · a
>
> “Additive identity” “Identity of +”: 0 + a = a
>
> “Multiplicative identity” “Identity of ·”: 1 · a = a
>
> “Distributivity of · over +”: a · (b + c) = a · b + a · c
>
> “Zero of ·”: a · 0 = 0
>
> “Unary minus”: a + (- a) = 0
>
> “Subtraction”: a - b = a + (- b)

I have no idea how to distribute the - sign at - (b - a) in to the parentheses.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you so much in advance.

Note: You can't add the same number/variable to the both sides or can't say
a - b + b - a = 0 by unary minus.

Clarification for note:

We use an online system to enter our proofs and we start with either one side or
both sides.
Exm:
Proof:
     a - b
     then we do the next step under it
Exm: a + (- b) - Subtraction
     however we cannot start by one side and make up another equality

Exm: a - b + b -a = 0 - by unary minus is not allowed we cannot put equality
sign if we started with only one side.

When we start with one side the goal is to get the same exact thing on the other side.
Exm: in this case after the proofs steps I need to end up with
     - (b - a)

Comment: Regarding your note, $a-b+b-a=a+(-b)+b+(-a)$ by rule "subtraction", and then by commutativity / symmetry of addition, and unary minus, it becomes $0$. How is that not allowed? Or are you saying it's not allowed as a "single step"? And why not add the same thing to both sides?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a-b\overset{Additive \ Identity}{=}$

$0+(a-b)\overset{Unary \ Minus}{=}$

$((b-a) + (-(b-a)))+(a-b)\overset{Symmetry \ of \ +}{=}$

$((-(b-a))+(b-a))+(a-b)\overset{Associativity \ of \ +}{=}$

$(-(b-a))+((b-a)+(a-b))\overset{Subtraction \ x \ 2}{=}$

$(-(b-a))+((b+(-a))+(a+(-b)))\overset{Associativity \ of \ +}{=}$

$(-(b-a))+(b+((-a)+(a+(-b))))\overset{Associativity \ of \ +}{=}$

$=(-(b-a))+(b+(((-a)+a)+(-b)))\overset{Symmetry \ of \ +}{=}$

$=(-(b-a))+(b+((a+(-a))+(-b)))\overset{Unary \ Minus}{=}$

$=(-(b-a))+(b+(0+(-b)))\overset{Additive \ Identity}{=}$

$=(-(b-a))+(b+(-b))\overset{Unary \ Minus}{=}$

$=(-(b-a))+0\overset{Symmetry \ of \ +}{=}$

$=0+(-(b-a))\overset{Additive \ Identity}{=}$

$=(-(b-a))$

Comment: Thank you so much. I was trying to do it from the right side, - (b - a), side and I couldn't figure it out. You just made my day!

Comment: @curiouseng Glad I could help!  You figured out the last steps at this point, I trust, so I added them to my Answer

Answer (score 0):

Use distributivity of multiplication over addition: We have that $a\cdot(b+c)=a\cdot\,b+a\cdot\,c$ therefore $-(b-a)=-1(b-a)=-1\cdot\,b+-1\cdot\,-a=-b+a=(a-b).$

Comment: Unfortunately the system we are using to enter our proofs gives an error when using the identity of * as - 1 * (b - a) but it allows as 1 * - (b - a). So, I can't really use the distributivity.

Comment: That requires first proving that $-a = (-1)\times a$ which is not included in the axioms listed above.  Granted, that is not hard to prove, but it is still left out from your proof here.

Answer (score 0):

Since $x=-y$ is equivalent to $x+y=0$, just evaluate $a-b+b-a$ with repeated use of addition's commutativity and associativity, and $-z+z=z-z=0$. The sum is $a+0-a=a-a=0$, as required.